# How to Append to Array Field in Python Django

Tags: python, arrays, django, windows, postgresql

I am making an E commerce site, I want to store Cart elements in an integer Array Field. I am using PostGreSql as my database.
I have created model for cart by extending Django User model. Here is my models

```
class UserCart(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_product=models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    cart_products = ArrayField(
        models.IntegerField(blank=True),
        default = list
    )

User.profile = property(lambda u:UserCart.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

Below is my Form.py. I have created only basic form
    from django import forms
    from .models import UserCart
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

```
class UserCartForm (forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model= UserCart
        fields = ('user_product',)
```

I have searched alot on internet but was unable to find the relevant answer.I want that whenever user clicks on Add to Cart button, that product_id gets stored in cart_products array.I read somewhere that ArrayFields behave as list in Django, so here is my views.py

```
@login_required
def user_cart(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=UserCartForm(request.POST , instance=request.user.profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.cart_products.append(99)
            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_login/loggedin')
        else:
            HttpResponse("Error")
    else:
        user=request.user
        profile=user.profile
        form= UserCartForm(instance=profile)
        args={}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args['form']=form
        return render_to_response('cartapi.html' ,args)
```

Its giving me Error that

```
 AttributeError at /cart/ac/
 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
 Request Method:    POST
 Request URL:   http://localhost:8000/cart/ac/
 Django Version:    1.11.2
 Exception Type:    AttributeError
 Exception Value:   
 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
 Exception Location:    C:\Users\Muhammad                
 Jawad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\mysite\cart\views.py in 
 user_cart, line 19
 Python Executable: C:\Users\Muhammad 
 Jawad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
```

And if i save cart_products this way

```
 post.cart_products=99
```

Then it throws this error

```
 column "cart_products" is of type int4range but expression is of type integer
 LINE 1: ...er_id" = 1, "user_cart" = 3000, "cart_products" = 99 WHERE "...
                                                         ^
 HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
 Request Method:    POST
 Request URL:   http://localhost:8000/cart/ac/
 Django Version:    1.11.2
 Exception Type:    ProgrammingError
 Exception Value:   
 column "cart_products" is of type int4range but expression is of type integer
 LINE 1: ...er_id" = 1, "user_cart" = 3000, "cart_products" = 99 WHERE "...
                                                         ^
 HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Kindly Help me in this matter.Summarizing my Question:
**How can i get user_product as id and save it in cart_products**

Comment: Can you append values in `cart_products` in terminal ?

Comment: Yes , I have tried, is giving the same error

Answer (score 0):

change yor views like this

## views.py

```
@login_required
def user_cart(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=UserCartForm(request.POST , instance=request.user.profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            if post.cart_products:
                post.cart_products.append(99)
            else:
                post.cart_products = [99]
            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_login/loggedin')
        else:
            HttpResponse("Error")
    else:
        user=request.user
        profile=user.profile
        form= UserCartForm(instance=profile)
        args={}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args['form']=form
        return render_to_response('cartapi.html' ,args)
```

Comment: Thanks For Answer but It is giving me Error that                                                                   
column "cart_products" is of type int4range but expression is of type integer[]
LINE 1: ...er_id" = 1, "user_cart" = 3000, "cart_products" = ARRAY[99] ...
                                                             ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Your database is messed up.  Drop it and remigrate (or craft a custom migration if you have data to preserve: basically, you just have to expand existing ranges into the full array).

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/contrib/postgres/fields/ranges/#IntegerRangeField

The `int4range` is the db type associated with the `IntegerRangeField`.  This indicates either problem with your migrations (try running `./manage.py makemigrations`) or that your database is out-of-sync with your DB (try running `./manage.py migrate`).

It's hard to say what exactly the problem is without looking at your migrations and the current table definition in the database, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

keyword_from_user="My name is John Doe"
I have Django 3.1.7 and this method has worked for me.

models.py

```
class Keys(models.Model):
    keys = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True),size=5,blank=True)
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py create object

```
new_document_object = Keys.objects.create(keys= keyword_from_user.split(), docfile =file)
```

views.py create object

```
new_document_object = Keys.objects.create(keys= keyword_from_user.split(), docfile =file)
```

views.py update object

```
keys = Keys.objects.get(id=id_from_user)
keys.keys=user_data['keyword_update_list']
keys.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save your cart_products into a **python list** then modify that list using the `append` method. Thereafter, you can save the new value of the list into the ArrayField

```
@login_required
def user_cart(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=UserCartForm(request.POST , instance=request.user.profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            # copy the existing cart_products to a temp variable
            temp_cart = post.cart_products
            # append your new product code to the temp_cart
            temp_cart.append(99)
            # save the new value of temp_cart to the cart_products field
            post.cart_products = temp_cart
            # save the post
            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_login/loggedin')
        else:
            HttpResponse("Error")
    else:
        user=request.user
        profile=user.profile
        form= UserCartForm(instance=profile)
        args={}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args['form']=form
        return render_to_response('cartapi.html' ,args)
```